# Calculate mean of data rows in dataframe with date-headers, dictated by a 'datetime'-column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, mean

I have a dataframe with ID's of clients and their expenses for 2014-2018. What I want is to have the mean of the expenses per ID but only the years before a certain date can be taken into account when calculating the mean value (so column 'Date' dictates which columns can be taken into account for the mean).

Example: for index 0 (ID: 12), the date states '2016-03-08', then the mean should be taken from the columns 'y_2014' and 'y_2015', so then for this index, the mean is 111.0.
If the date is too early (e.g. somewhere in 2014 or earlier in this case), then NaN should be returned (see index 6 and 9).

**Initial dataframe:**

```
   y_2014  y_2015  y_2016  y_2017  y_2018        Date  ID  
0   100.0   122.0     324     632     NaN  2016-03-08  12   
1   120.0   159.0      54     452   541.0  2015-04-09  96   
2     NaN   164.0     687     165   245.0  2016-02-15  20   
3   180.0   421.0     512     184   953.0  2018-05-01  73  
4   110.0   654.0     913     173   103.0  2017-08-04  84   
5   130.0     NaN     754     124   207.0  2016-07-03  26   
6   170.0   256.0     843      97   806.0  2013-02-04  87    
7   140.0   754.0      95     101   541.0  2016-06-08  64    
8    80.0   985.0     184      84    90.0  2019-03-05  11  
9    96.0    65.0     127     130   421.0  2014-05-14  34
```

**Desired output:**

```
   y_2014  y_2015  y_2016  y_2017  y_2018        Date  ID    mean
0   100.0   122.0     324     632     NaN  2016-03-08  12   111.0
1   120.0   159.0      54     452   541.0  2015-04-09  96   120.0
2     NaN   164.0     687     165   245.0  2016-02-15  20   164.0
3   180.0   421.0     512     184   953.0  2018-05-01  73  324.25
4   110.0   654.0     913     173   103.0  2017-08-04  84   559.0
5   130.0     NaN     754     124   207.0  2016-07-03  26   130.0
6   170.0   256.0     843      97   806.0  2013-02-04  87     NaN
7   140.0   754.0      95     101   541.0  2016-06-08  64     447
8    80.0   985.0     184      84    90.0  2019-03-05  11   284.6
9    96.0    65.0     127     130   421.0  2014-05-14  34     NaN
```

**Tried code:** -> I'm still working on it, as I don't really know how to start for this, I only uploaded the dataframe so far, probably something with the 'datetime'-package has to be done to get the desired dataframe?

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":   [12,96,20,73,84,26,87,64,11,34],  
                 "y_2014": [100,120,np.nan,180,110,130,170,140,80,96],    
                 "y_2015": [122,159,164,421,654,np.nan,256,754,985,65],      
                 "y_2016": [324,54,687,512,913,754,843,95,184,127],    
                 "y_2017": [632,452,165,184,173,124,97,101,84,130],    
                 "y_2018": [np.nan,541,245,953,103,207,806,541,90,421],  
                 "Date": ['2016-03-08', '2015-04-09', '2016-02-15', '2018-05-01', '2017-08-04',                           
                          '2016-07-03', '2013-02-04', '2016-06-08', '2019-03-05', '2014-05-14']}) 
print(df)
```

Comment: Where does this data come from? _probably something with the 'datetime'-package has to be done to get the desired dataframe?_ Pandas includes functionality for handling dates and times.

Comment: It's just some example data to test the operation, I can't share the actual dataset ;-) ok yes, I'll look some more into that.

Comment: _ok yes, I'll look some more into that._ Please do, and report back when there is a specific issue.

Comment: wow, you definitely give the most helpful comments around here.. This forum is open for all sorts of code-related questions. This is a question in which I really put effort, defining the problem, providing an example, if I knew the answer, I wouldn't ask so if this is the best you can say, I would just be quite ;) Many thanks.

Comment: _wow, you definitely give the most helpful comments around here.._ You are not entitled to an answer. _if I knew the answer, I wouldn't ask_ With all due respect, I'm not sure I understand what that has to do with my comment, which was nowhere near rude or inflammatory. _This forum is open for all sorts of code-related questions._ This is not a forum in the typical sense, and there are still rules and conventions to follow. _so if this is the best you can say, I would just be quite ;) Many thanks._ Again, you aren't entitled to an answer and immune from everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one more answer:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np  

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":   [12,96,20,73,84,26,87,64,11,34],                  
               "y_2014": [100,120,np.nan,180,110,130,170,140,80,96],    
               "y_2015": [122,159,164,421,654,np.nan,256,754,985,65],                  
               "y_2016": [324,54,687,512,913,754,843,95,184,127],   
               "y_2017": [632,452,165,184,173,124,97,101,84,130],                  
               "y_2018": [np.nan,541,245,953,103,207,806,541,90,421],   
                 "Date": ['2016-03-08', '2015-04-09', '2016-02-15', '2018-05-01', '2017-08-04',                
                          '2016-07-03', '2013-02-04', '2016-06-08', '2019-03-05', '2014-05-14']})

#Subset from original df to calculate mean
subset = df.loc[:,['y_2014', 'y_2015', 'y_2016', 'y_2017', 'y_2018']] 

#an expense value is only available for the calculation of the mean when that year has passed, therefore 2015-01-01 is chosen for the 'y_2014' column in the subset etc. to check with the 'Date'-column
subset.columns = ['2015-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01']  
s = subset.columns[0:].values < df.Date.values[:,None] 
t = s.astype(float)
t[t == 0] = np.nan 

df['mean'] = (subset.iloc[:,0:]*t).mean(1)  
print(df)

#Additionally: (gives the sum of expenses before a certain date in the 'Date'-column
df['sum'] = (subset.iloc[:,0:]*t).sum(1)  
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to your naming convention, one need to extract the years from column names for comparison purpose. Then you can mask the data and taking mean:

```
# the years from columns
data = df.filter(like='y_')
data_years = data.columns.str.extract('(\d+)')[0].astype(int)

# the years from Date
years = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.year.values

df['mean'] = data.where(data_years<years[:,None]).mean(1)
```

Output:

```
   y_2014  y_2015  y_2016  y_2017  y_2018       Date  ID    mean
0   100.0   122.0     324     632     NaN 2016-03-08  12  111.00
1   120.0   159.0      54     452   541.0 2015-04-09  96  120.00
2     NaN   164.0     687     165   245.0 2016-02-15  20  164.00
3   180.0   421.0     512     184   953.0 2018-05-01  73  324.25
4   110.0   654.0     913     173   103.0 2017-08-04  84  559.00
5   130.0     NaN     754     124   207.0 2016-07-03  26  130.00
6   170.0   256.0     843      97   806.0 2013-02-04  87     NaN
7   140.0   754.0      95     101   541.0 2016-06-08  64  447.00
8    80.0   985.0     184      84    90.0 2019-03-05  11  284.60
9    96.0    65.0     127     130   421.0 2014-05-14  34     NaN
```

Comment: When I run it, I get the following error: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')

Comment: That line of code is to extract the values `2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018` from `y_2014  y_2015  y_2016  y_2017  y_2018`. I'm not sure what your actual data column names are.

Comment: the actual data columns are similar, a string with 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018 in it, that's why I defined them like this ;) so indeed extracting the year from the headers seems a good start, but what causes the error then?